# using iptables nat to connect two machines unaware of each other

Tags: networking, routing, iptables, nat, man-in-the-middle

I have done it several times in the past, but after more than 10 years that I've been away from networking, I just cannot make it work again:

I have three machines, A B and C. Both A and B can see C, but they cannot directly access each other and they don't even have the other machine's IP address. So I want to use C to make a bridge between them.

Let's say I want to telnet from A to B, I did the following on C using ufw:

```
-A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 23 -j DNAT --to-destination "A":23
-A POSTROUTING -d "A" -j SNAT --to-source "C"
```

What I expect now, but it is not happening: When I try to telnet C from B, I should telnet A instead.

Comment: What _is_ happening? Fire up tcpdump / Wireshark / termshark and check what the packets look like (both those forwarded by C to A, and those returning from A to C).

Comment: Well, I was wondering if the iptables setup is not right. If it seems OK, I will get more deep to find the problem.